# Can we run for loops inside a conditional operator (? :)?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary

i have this code:

```
function f(n){
var p = 0;
if(n % 2 === 0 && n > 0) {
  for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    p += i;
  };
} else {
    return false;
    }
 return p;
};
```

And was wondering if it was possible to convert to ternary operator to shorted it. This is the code i have come up with but its obviously incorrect, any insight would be good! Cheers.

```
function f(n){
  var p = 0;
  ((n % 2 === 0) && (n > 0)) ? for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {p += i;} : 
  false;
  return p;
}
```

Comment: have you tried it? what happened?

Comment: Per [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-conditional-operator), The bits either side of the `:` need to be [*assignment expressions*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-AssignmentExpression), they can't contain [*statements or declarations*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations) like a [*for* statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-for-statement).

Comment: provide more context, if n is an array we can give you a better answer. You can use every and some in place of a for loop in a conditional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd use Gauss and write it this way:

```js
function f(n)
{
  return n > 0 && n % 2 === 0 ? n * (n + 1) / 2 : false;
}

console.log(f(4));
console.log(f(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only expressions inside of a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). A [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) statement is not an expression.

But you could use a ternary statement, without `for` loop and the Gausss formular for getting the result for even numbers.

```js
function f(n) {
    return n % 2 === 0 && n > 0 ? n * (n + 1) / 2 : false;
}

console.log(f(4));
console.log(f(5));
```

An even shorter version could utilize the [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_())

```js
function f(n) {
    return n % 2 === 0 && n > 0 && n * (n + 1) / 2;
}

console.log(f(4));
console.log(f(5));
```

The other possibillity is to wrap the whole `for` statement in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```js
function f(n){
    return n % 2 === 0 && n > 0 ? function (p) {
        for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            p += i;
        }
        return p;
    }(0) : false;
}

console.log(f(4));
console.log(f(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cano't use for inside a ternary if,
Insted you can use a function to do the `for` to you :

```js
function calc(num){
  var p = 0;
   for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
     p += i;
   }
   
   return p;
}

function f(n){
  var p = 0;
  p = ((n % 2 === 0) && (n > 0)) ? calc(n) : 
  false;
  return p;
}

console.log(f(4));
console.log(f(5));
```

Comment: In that case, the conditional is redundant: `n % 2 === 0 && n > 0 && calc(n)`. ;-)

Comment: Haha , that's the only way to use for inside ternary conditional